# What is the pattern here: 1,2,5,10,13,26,39...

Tags: sequences-and-series

At first the pattern starts out ×2, +3, ×2, +3, ×2, but then jumps to +13? Can't see what the full pattern is. Any ideas?

Comment: [OEIS](http://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C2%2C5%2C10%2C13%2C26%2C39) is inconclusive.

Comment: Do you have access to more entries of this pattern?

Comment: Probably a typo :)

Comment: a typo?$ $ $ $ $ $

Comment: Yes, a typo of $29\to 39$...

Comment: A [typo](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/typo).

Comment: @Jaiden are other known subsequent numbers of the sequence? If any, it can be helpful if you post them.

Comment: no pattern, 39 is the last one of the next week lottery winning numbers :-)

Comment: There are no other numbers given @the_candyman

Answer (score 1):

One possible answer is the following:

$$\mbox{even terms}=\mbox{twice the odd terms}$$
$$\mbox{ odd terms}=  \mbox{odd term} + 3+ 10*\lfloor \frac{\mbox{odd term}}{20} \rfloor$$

To keep it simple, instead of adding 3, add 3+ half the tens of the previous numbers.